# How to delete .svn files of remote repo in GitHub via Egit or Git Bash?

Tags: git, svn, github, egit, git-bash

I'm working under Windows and synchronize local and Github repo through Eclipse egit.
I just find that my repo on GitHub remote contains some hidden .svn folders. Those files and folders can not be seen in the egit sync view, and I added a .gitignore file but seems too late.

How to delete those files of remote repo in GitHub via egit or Git Bash (I'm totally a noob of GitBash)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run `git bash`, you'll get the command prompt
2. Change directory to your repository using `cd <directory>` command. Use `ls` and/or `pwd` to get the idea where you are now and where to go.
3. In the repository directory issue the following command: `find . -type d -name .svn` to ensure that .svn folders are actually in.
4. If they are, run something like this : `find . -type d -name .svn -exec git rm -rf {} \;`.
5. Review your changes using `git status`
6. Commit the changes using `git commit`
7. Push them to github using `git push <github remote url>`. Also you may use Eclipse egit to synchronize repositories as usually.

Comment: Wow,lots of thks for the step-by-step explaination